# Angular 6 Interactive recursive List of objects

Tags: angular, list

I'm trying to display a structure of users in a recursive list with the ability to display some info about any of them

so far i have managed to properly display them but cant seem to make it able to display info about any other that the highest one (no matter which i click on it always displays info about admin)

getUsersID(number) returns list containing a single user (in this case admin id 1 which is the highest user)

and user model has all its subordinates stored in `podrizeni: User[];`

strom.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-strom',
  templateUrl: './strom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./strom.component.css']
})
export class StromComponent implements OnInit {
  //@Input () users: User [];
  users: User[];
  user: User;
  selectedUser: User;
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService  
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers().subscribe(users => {

      this.users = users;
      this.users.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user);
      });
    });
  }

  getUsers() {
   return this.userService.getUsersID(1)

  }
  onSelect(user: User): void {
    this.selectedUser = user;
  }
}
```

strom.html:

```
<ul>
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-users>

    <li *ngFor="let user of users" [class.selected]="user === selectedUser" (click)="onSelect(user)">
          {{user.username}}
          <ul *ngIf="user.podrizeni">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: user.podrizeni}"></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: users }"></ng-container>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="selectedUser">

  <h2>{{selectedUser.username | uppercase}} Details</h2>
  <div>
    <span>id: </span>{{selectedUser.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: {{selectedUser.username}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using `ng-container` and `ng-template` in here?

Comment: i was trying to call back the entire function, and since im pretty new to angular and pretty much everything i found used them then so did i

Comment: Can you put this in a StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Would it be better to do `[class.selected]="user.id === selectedUser.id"`? I would also delete the user property from the component.

Comment: @christo8989 i will definetly try to put it on stackBlitz as soon as i make necessary modifications for that

Comment: @christo8989 i cant seem to make it work even on stackblitz as im failing to load data from any fake json site [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acfkyt )
here is the json im getting from api     https://pastebin.com/7DxsTaeb
if case need be i can modify api to return what ever is necessary

Comment: You should look at @SiddharthAjmera's answer. That looks like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this sample [StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-recursive-list) that I created for you. Let me know if this is something that you want to implement.

You can see a users list. Once you click on a user, it makes an API call to get the users' posts. In your case, it would call `userService.getUsersID`. Consider `userPosts` as `podrizeni` for your case.

Also, I've done everything in the AppComponent for the sake of brevity. In your case, it should be as you've implemented it.

Plus, you should create a separate component for Subordinate Users List. That should accept a userId. And the responsibility to call the `userService.getUsersID(userId)` should be of the Subordinate Users List component and not this parent users list component.

Comment: what i was trying to make was basicly something like this https://netbasal.com/recursion-in-angular-components-1cd636269b12
except with onlz one root user and unknown number of subordinates and subordinates of subordinates etc... with info window bellow it showing some basic information like name and email of selected user from the tree

Comment: I've updated the code on the StackBlitz project. Have a look at it now.

Comment: yes thats pretty much what im trying to achieve, do you think it would work with this sort of input 
https://pastebin.com/7DxsTaeb
as this is what im getting from my backend

Comment: Of course, it would. You'll just have to make the appropriate changes to support this response structure. Ideally, your API should not send you the list of `podrizeni` right away. There should be a separate endpoint for that. That endpoint should take userId as a request/query param and should return the list of subordinates accordingly.

Comment: i have tried modifying it but all im getting is a non-hierarchycal list that just loads onto itself nothing like https://imgur.com/a/oaKacYd where my problem is on the other hand that no matter what i click on it always shows details for root user

Comment: I've used the `$event.stopPropagation();` in the user component for the same reason. You'll have to make the relevant changes for your Data Structure. A lot has been spoonfed already.

Comment: ok solved the problem in my code all i was missing was really      $event.stopPropagation(); in my on select method thx for your help and pointing that out :)